# drag and drop items between sections

Tags: html, reactjs

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxTAc.png)

I have two sections. I want to drag and drop elements between that two sections, but here's the element is appending but I need to drop the element at the first in that sections. When we drop the element it should place as first element for that section.

this is my code:

```
class Sections extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {

             sections: [
                            {   

                                "idFolder":1,
                                "idUser":1,
                                "title":"Your Materials",
                                "products":[
                                            {   "id":1,
                                                "productType":"textile",
                                                "name":"cotton"
                                                "images":[
                                                            {
                                                                "original_file_name":"bear.jpeg"
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                            },
                                            {   "id":3,
                                                "productType":"textile",
                                                "name":"cotton"
                                            }
                                        ]

                            },
                            {   

                                "idFolder":2,
                                "idUser":1,
                                "title":"Your Materials",
                                "products":[
                                            {   "id":5,
                                                "productType":"textile",
                                                "name":"cotton"

                                            },
                                            {   "id":6,
                                                "productType":"textile",
                                                "name":"cotton"
                                            }
                                        ]

                            }
                        ]
            }
        };

         onDragStart(e){
                    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
                    e.dataTransfer.setData( "text", e.target.getAttribute('id'));
                }

        allowDrop (ev){
                    ev.preventDefault();
                }

        onDrop(e){
                  const data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
                 e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

        }

        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                <div className="row">

                    {
                        this.state.sections.map((sec_head, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={index} className="sec_container">
                                    <h4  data-toggle="collapse" data-target={'#'+sec_head.idFolder}>{sec_head.title}</h4>
                                    <ul id="list" className="sec_cont collapse in" id={sec_head.idFolder} 
                                        onDrop={this.onDrop}
                                        onDragOver={this.allowDrop}
                                        >

                                        {
                                            sec_head.products.map((product, i) => {
                                                return(
                                                    <li 
                                                        index={i} key={i} className="sec_items col-md-3 alert alert-dismissable"
                                                        onDragStart={ (e) => this.onDragStart(e) } 
                                                        id={product.id} draggable="true" 
                                                        >
                                                        <a href="#" className="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>

                                                                    <img  />

                                                        <h5>{product.name}</h5>


                                                    </li>


                                                )
                                            })
                                        }


                                    </ul>

                                </div>
                               )
                            })
                    }

                </div>

                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for your question. When posting code, please make sure it is indented correctly and consistently. [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) should help you understand the topic better. Almost every modern text editor and IDE have the option to automatically indent code for you.